# How can i define a default value for react-select v1

Tags: reactjs, select, default

I had a react-select rendering a list of emails, and i need to keep the selected emails as a default option when the email is selected and saved, but the defaultValues are not working. How can i do that?

Here is my select component:

```
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("")

  const makeEmailOption = item => ({
    value: item.id,
    label: item.ccEmail,
    id: item.id,
    chipLabel: item.ccEmail,
    rest: item,
    selected: item.selected
  })
  const makeEmailOptions = items => items.map(makeEmailOption)

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setSelectedOption(value)
    props.emails(value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        multi={true}
        name={props.name}
        options={makeEmailOptions(props.ccemailfilter)} 
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={selectedOption} 
      />
    </div>
  )
```

I receive everything as props and work with that to make the options. How can i do that to make the default value if a field selected is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with the following solution, since my component use a function to set some variables to the select, i use a useEffect to call that with a filter right after the page render.

```
  useEffect(()  => {
     handleChange(makeEmailOption(props.ccemailfilter.filter(x => x.selected)))
  }, [])

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setSelectedOption(value)
    props.emails(value)
  }
```

So, the handleChange are called on the onChange of the select and once after the page loads, to create a value to the select to use.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it, but in this case, you are setting the `value` to the `selectedOption` instead of setting the `defaultValue`. Also, you are changing the default value each time there is a change, which shouldn't be needed.

```
const defaultVal = {value: selectedOption, label: selectedOption};

return (
  <div>
    <Select
      multi={true}
      name={props.name}
      options={makeEmailOptions(props.ccemailfilter)} 
      defaultValue={defaultVal} 
    />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Didn't work, i get cant even select the options when i use that. Dont know where to go from here

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example? Can you upload it to an online sandbox?

Comment: I dont think that i can do that, the select is rendered in a file, that is being rendered from another file. The code i put in the question is the final select that receives all the info from other files and set on the select itself.

Comment: I forgot that you needed to specify a value and a label; you can't just pass in the value like i had it before. Try this answer

Comment: Your answer is not wrong, but didn't work on my case for a reason i dont understand. I answer my question with the solution i came up with.Thank you anyway